# mApp Mobile Application Framework usable with datagrid form layout?

Tags: livecode

Monte's Mobile Application Framework (mApp) works with datagrids in table form ok as it's straightforward to scale for various screen sizes and resolutions.

What do we need to do to get it to work with datagrid form layouts ok? i.e. Can we use it for the form layout contents also? If so, how?

cheers, Alan

Answer (score 0):

mApp is completely untested for DataGrid table layouts which I can't imagine are all that helpful on a mobile. If it works then great.

For form layouts you just need to remember that any fixed pixel widths in your layout need to be multiplied by mAppPixelDensity() then rounded. The templates are scaled automatically. The default LayoutControl handler should therefore be changed to this:

```
on LayoutControl pControlRect
    local theFieldRect

    -- This message is sent when you should layout your template's controls.
    -- This is where you resize the 'Background' graphic, resize fields and 
    -- position objects.
    -- For fixed height data grid forms you can use items 1 through 4 of pControlRect as
    -- boundaries for laying out your controls.
    -- For variable height data grid forms you can use items 1 through 3 of pControlRect as
    -- boundaries, expanding the height of your control as needed.

    -- Example:
    put the rect of field "Label" of me into theFieldRect
    put item 3 of pControlRect - round(5*mAppPixelDensity()) into item 3 of theFieldRect
    set the rect of field "Label" of me to theFieldRect

    set the rect of graphic "Background" of me to pControlRect
end LayoutControl
```